# Sub-interfaces vs. Interfaces

Tags: juniper-mx

I was recently advised I should not be using VLAN interfaces for connections to upstream peers.

On a Juniper MX what, if any, are the cons of using VLANs on an aggregated interface rather than dedicated physical interfaces?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you mean using a switch to break out your 10g router port into individual VLANs and then using subinterfaces to route each port individually, I don't see how that is really wrong. Yes you'll lose the immediate failover when the physical port goes down, but as they say that's the "cost of doing business". Router ports are expensive compared to switch ports so I assume that is a business decision.